# Using angular2 with asp.net 5 Razor view

Tags: angular

In Angular 1 we set `ng-controller` for any HTML tag in the Razor view and use the functions defined in the angular controller. How I can achieve this view Angular2?
For example I want to click on a HTML tag in Razor View and call a method from an angular2 component or directive.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The controller is basically the component constructor now. The controller methods are now the component methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is I searching for ?

- A framework with `Angularjs` functionalities but simpler like
  `Angular2`.

Angular2 unfortunately start the app whit one component and what I want (multi components in on page) not possible.

I would like to experiment `Vue` (a framework that bring angular 1 and 2 together).

Answer (score 0):

There is no more concept of controller in Angular. Views are now managed by components.

Within template associated with a component, you can leverage its methods and its state. Here is a sample below:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CompanyService, Company} from './app.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'company-list',
    template: `
      <h1>Companies</h1>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#company of companies">
          <a href="#" (click)="selectCompany(company)">
            {{company.name}}
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    `
})
export class ListComponent {
  constructor(service:CompanyService,router:Router) {
    this.service = service;
    this.companies = service.getCompanies();
  }

  selectCompany(company:Company) {
    (...)
    return false;
  }
}
```

The `click` event is attached to the `selectCompany` method using the syntax `(click)`.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for elaborating Thierry. My issue is adding behavior to existing HTML tags. I don't want to having template.

Comment: I create a plunker to clarify what is in mind.Please look at it here.http://plnkr.co/edit/TpsBwe?p=preview